# Liquibase Stored Procedure

Tags: database, db2, database-migration, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am trying to call Liquibase Stored Procedure  Through Tag

it gives me error as sql code

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

I Am Tring to call as follows : :

```
<sql> CALL TestProcedure('abc','xyz') </sql>
```

it executed well from outside command line Client and not using liquibase

i also tried calling using schema name no luck Open to suggestions

Comment: i am calling like      <sql> CALL TestProcedure('abc','xyz') </sql>

Comment: What is the liquibase version?  Which operating-system are you running liquibase on?  Have you enabled logging for liquibase to see what it is doing under the covers?

Comment: Works fine for me with liquibase 3.6.2 on Linux with Db2-LUW v11.1.  So your symptom (SQL0440N) may result from liquibase using a different database than the command-line, wrong sproc name, or wrong sproc signature, or sproc does not exist in specified or implied schema.

Answer (score 0):

`SQL440N` is routine not found. The error message should give the text of the rountine name. Does it match what you have in your database. Is is a case sensitive problem? (i.e. try in upper case?)

```
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "<routine-name>" of type
      "<routine-type>" having compatible arguments was found.
```